# MySQL - Error In SQL Syntax 1064 workbench

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I am working on a point of sale system and when I want to generate the sales ticket I use this query:

```
SELECT     v.cod_venta, 
           v.date_venta, 
           v.total_venta, 
           v.pago, 
           v.discounts, 
           ( 
                  SELECT p.name_person 
                  FROM   person p 
                  WHERE  v_user_codefk = p.cod_person) AS username, 
           ( 
                  SELECT p.person_name 
                  FROM   person p 
                  WHERE  v.cod_client_fk = p.cod_person) AS client_name, 
           d.cod_productfk, 
           ( 
                  SELECT p.product_name 
                  FROM   product p 
                  WHERE  p.cod_product = d.cod_productofk) AS productname, 
           ( 
                  SELECT Sum (d.quantidad_detalle)) AS totalquantity, 
           ( 
                  SELECT Sum (d.subtotal)) AS subtotalprod, 
           d.precio_producto 
FROM       sale v 
INNER JOIN detail_venta d 
ON         v.cod_venta = d.cod_ventafk 
WHERE      v.cod_venta = $ p {cod_venta} 
AND        v.tipo_comprobante = 'Boleta' 
GROUP BY   d.cod_productofk ASC)
```

> But it is giving me a "null" error, when running the query in MySQL Workbench it throws this error (Error Code: 1064 . You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for t he right syntax to use near '{cod_venta} AND v.tipo_comprobante =' Boleta 'GROUP by d.cod_productoFK ASC' at line 1)

Could someone help me with this please?

Im using a MacBook Pro, Neatbeans, JasperReports, MYSQL Workbench

Comment: What is your expectation that `WHERE v.cod_venta = $ P {cod_venta} AND v.tipo_comprobante = 'Boleta'` would filter? Looks like some kind of failed variable substitution...?

Comment: Nice point Im going to review that